# Excel Formula Calculation IF AND ETC

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can't use a picture, because of reputation. I try to explain my problem. Please help me for my formula.

I have a table 1. I have to enter alphabet on the column 1 and column 2 on this table. For ex. I entered A on the column 1 and X on the column 2. I also have table 2. Table 2 have column 3 column 4 and column 5. column 3 and column 4 are alphabet like table 1's columns. Also column 5 is a number. When I enter these alphabets (A and X) on the table 1's columns, my formula scan the table 2's column 3 and column 4 for each lines. If column 1 = column 3 and column 2 = column 4, formula plus the column 5 for each line and write the table 3's single column.

** ALSO Formula can't plus negative numbers.

FOR EXAMPLE.

**TABLE 1**
COLUMN 1 : A
COLUMN 2 : X

**TABLE 2**
LINE 1 - COLUMN 3 : **A**
         COLUMN 4 : **C**
         COLUMN 5 : **50**

LINE 2 - COLUMN 3 : **A**
         COLUMN 4 : **X**
         COLUMN 5 : **60**

LINE 3 - COLUMN 3 : **A**
         COLUMN 4 : **X**
         COLUMN 5 : **-20**

LINE 4 - COLUMN 3 : **A**
         COLUMN 4 : **X**
         COLUMN 5 : **40**

**TABLE 3**
TOTAL : **100**

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what your formula exactly makes... but this is the sintax of IF:

`IF(boolean statement, instruction if true , instruction if false).`

you can read this for more information about if: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx

the column 3, 4 and 5 depends on the content of the column 1 and 2... so you can build some logical function with the IF formula in the columns 3, 4 and 5.

the result in TABLE 3 sums the positive numbers of the lines that have an 'X' on the column 4...
you can use the SUMIFS function to achieve this... the SUMIFS function sums a range of cells if they meet certain logical criterias. Here, i made this function that throws the total value of the table 4:

`SUMIFS(E1:E4;D1:D4;"=X";E1:E4;">0")`

read this for more informationo about SUMIFS: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA102753226.aspx?CTT=1

also, i suggest you to use the wizard to build your SUMIFS formula... it's pretty friendly.